# Room Persistence can not create table even a add new Item @insert

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, android-room

Creating One Db where one table with Room Persistence but, after insert data getting Primary Id as increase but, no data storing in Database.

here, i am try to insert image and check db in Root folder but table is empty and not getting data by @LiveData also getting Null due to Empty table.

And this execute in BackGround thread. No Error or No Crash.

```
@Dao
public interface DaoAccess {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertImage(Album album);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Album WHERE lessonid=:lessonid ORDER BY orderumber desc")
    LiveData<List<Album>> fetchAllImages(int lessonid);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Album WHERE lessonid=:lessonid ORDER BY orderumber desc limit 1")
    LiveData<Album> fetchLastImage(int lessonid);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Album WHERE id =:imageId")
    LiveData<Album> getImage(int imageId);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Album")
    LiveData<List<Album>> fetchAllImages();

    @Update
    void updateImage(Album album);

    @Delete
    void deleteImage(Album album);
}
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "Album")
public class Album {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Long id;

    private int lessonId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "orderumber")
    private int order;

    private String filePath;

    private int width;
    private int height;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getLessonId() {
        return lessonId;
    }

    public void setLessonId(int lessonid) {
        this.lessonId = lessonid;
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public String getFilePath() {
        return filePath;
    }

    public void setFilePath(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

```
@Database(entities = {Album.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class AlbumDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract DaoAccess daoAccess();
}
```

```
public class AlbumRepository {

    private String DB_NAME = "db_images";

    private AlbumDatabase albumDatabase;

    public AlbumRepository(Context context) {
        albumDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AlbumDatabase.class, DB_NAME).build();
    }

    public void insertImage(Integer lessonid, String filePath, Integer width, Integer height) {
        Album album = new Album();
        album.setLessonId(lessonid);
        album.setFilePath(filePath);
        album.setWidth(width);
        album.setHeight(height);

        int newOrderId = 1;

        LiveData<Album> data = albumDatabase.daoAccess().fetchLastImage(lessonid);
        if (data != null && data.getValue() != null) {
            newOrderId = data.getValue().getOrder();
        }

        album.setOrder(newOrderId);
        albumDatabase.daoAccess().insertImage(album);
    }

    public void updateImage(final Album album) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                albumDatabase.daoAccess().updateImage(album);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public void deleteImage(final int id) {
        final LiveData<Album> task = getImage(id);
        if (task != null) {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                    albumDatabase.daoAccess().deleteImage(task.getValue());
                    return null;
                }
            }.execute();
        }
    }

    public void deleteImage(final Album album) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                albumDatabase.daoAccess().deleteImage(album);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public LiveData<Album> getImage(int id) {
        return albumDatabase.daoAccess().getImage(id);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Album>> getImages(int lessonid) {
        return albumDatabase.daoAccess().fetchAllImages(lessonid);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Album>> fetchAllImages() {
        return albumDatabase.daoAccess().fetchAllImages();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try increase the version of database: version: 2 in AlbumDatabase